# Wordpress code causing 404 errors

Tags: wordpress

I am receiving 404 errors (showing on Google search console)that somehow relate to Facebook.

eg  http://www.beerandcroissants.com/staying-in-mykonos-myconian-k-hotel/room-at-myconian-k-hotel-mykonos/%22https:/www.facebook.com/pages/Beer-and-croissants/1423705111261254

What it seems to be doing is taking one link (eg part of the whole link above) which relates to a photo on my blog and then appending the facebook page url.    So, if I take the first part of the link above 
(before the facebook part starts) I get a perfectly good link through to my site.  If I take the second part (where the facebook link starts) then it takes me to my FB page.  Again fine.

Why are these two linking together like this as it is this that seems to be causing the 404.  Is it something in my settings.  It's only just started happening.

Going to facebook directly and clicking on my post links takes me to the correct part of my blog.

I am not sure how to fix this.  There are no broken links attached in google for me to view either.  They keep happening every day.  I now have 295 crawl errors and growing.

Would appreciate any help that can be given to lead me in the right direction.

I've had this as a suggestion....but don't know where to look for this code....

I'd say it may be coming from the following code on :staying-in-mykonos-myconian-k-hotel/room-at-myconian-k-hotel-mykonos/
It's also likely this is carried through the entire site.

https://www.facebook.com/pages/Beer-and-croissants/1423705111261254">

Note the " in the URL before https://www.facebook

I suggest you go through your code looking for similar issues.

Could someone please assist me if they are able.

Greatly appreciated.

thanks
Kerri

Comment: You should probably use the tag "wordpress", because this isn't really about facebook or http-status-code-404, but about wp inserting those obsolete escaped quotes. And change the title to something that better describes your problem. Btw, there is a Wordpress forum on Stack Exchange where you might find help with this problem more easily than on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you for all of that information, really helpful.  I've never used stack exchange before.  I will do all of what you have suggested.